# VS Installer adds unidentified dependency

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, installation

I am creating an installation package for a VB6 application using Visual Studio Installer from the Visual Studio Installer Enterprise Tools v6.0. My issue is that Installer is adding a strange item under depdendencies, named simply "3". The "Sourcefile" and "Target" properties for this item are also shown as just "3". The "ComponentId" property values shows a GUID of "{EC1441E1-073C-4AD6-886F-1C6C6E998CAD}", which doesn't show up in a search within regedit on my PC. I'm not able to identify anything within the references or components of the VB6 project that would explain a dependency on a file named simply "3".

Has anyone seen this before, or have some insight as to where that dependency might be coming from?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No malware - searches on the net found others with the same issue, but no resolutions. Builds done since then no longer have the dependency, so it remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

May be some maleware COM component! Do a thorough scan of your computer with a good antivirus.

And oh yes if it isn't malware then unregister the dependency from the registry using

`regsvr32 /u <offending guid>`

and then re-run your application to see if it crashes (do a thorough test) if not then you dont need it. If it does then debug and find out who is using it.